# JavaScript "if" statement wont run

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

(Using Javascript)
If I enter text in the textbox or not, the alert will not come up.
I know this is a simple fix but I can not figure it out!
(This is for learning purposes.)

Workout Log Test

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myResults() {
    myExercise();
    myWeight();
    mySets();
    myReps();
    myFunction();
}

function myExercise() {
        var txtExercise = document.getElementById("txtExercise");
        var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput1");
        var name = txtExercise.value;
        txtOutput1.value = "You destroyed, " + name + "!"

        if (txtExercise.length === 0) {
            alert ('Do you even lift?');
            return;
```

Comment: Is that all of the code, because its missing the two closing }'s

Comment: Can you share you HTML as well?

Comment: I think we could use some more code here -- are you binding myExercise() to an event (e.g., `submit` or `change` for an input)?

Comment: did you mean to test against name.length? txtExercise.length will be undefined as dom elements do not usually have a length property

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're checking the "length" property of the element rather than the value of the input.

Second of all, you're checking against an integer value. If you were to simply read the `value` of the element, you're going to get text.

I'm guessing, what you want is something like:

```
var exercise = parseInt(txtExercise.value, 10);
if(exercise === 0) {
    alert('Do you even lift?');
    return;
}
```

But that's assuming `txtExercise` is an input element. Without seeing your markup, it's hard to be sure that any given answer will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, all fixed. You need an event handler, and this is a better if/else use case.

http://codepen.io/davidwickman/pen/vOKjqV

```
// Check the .value.length instead of just the .length
if (txtExercise.value.length === 0) {
  alert('Bro, do you even lift?');
} else {
  txtOutput1.value = "You destroyed, " + name + "!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have closed the function and if statement properly, you are missing a semi colon just before the if statement.

```
 txtOutput1.value = "You destroyed, " + name + "!";  <---- here
```